# Cannot use large matrix scale service : 403 Forbidden message - These credentials do not authorize access

Tags: matrix, here-api

I've succeeded to get the token to launch request on the large scale matrix webservice (freemium). I managed to use the health, version and profiles services, but when I try to use the matrix service, I have the following response :

{
"error": "Forbidden",
"error_description": "These credentials do not authorize access"
}

I use the following body for my request with Postman :

```
    {
      "origins": [
        {
          "lat": 52.53787,
          "lng": 13.40896
        },
        {
          "lat": 52.52387,
          "lng": 13.70346
        }
      ],
      "destinations": [
        {
          "lat": 52.53787,
          "lng": 13.40896
       }
      ],
  "regionDefinition": {
    "type": "circle",
    "center": {
      "lat": 52.53787,
      "lng": 13.40896
    },
    "radius": 10000
  },
  "profile": "carFast",
  "departureTime": "string",
  "routingMode": "fast",
  "transportMode": "car",
  "avoid": {
    "features": [
      "tollRoad"
    ],
    "areas": [
      {
        "type": "string",
        "north": -90,
        "south": -90,
        "west": -180,
        "east": -180
      }
    ]
  },
  "truckOptions": {
    "shippedHazardousGoods": [
      "explosive"
    ],
    "grossWeight": 0,
    "weightPerAxle": 0,
    "height": 0,
    "width": 0,
    "length": 0,
    "tunnelCategory": "B",
    "weightLimit": 0
  },
  "matrixAttributes": [
    "travelTimes"
  ]
}
```

Did I miss a authentification step before using the service ?

Comment: Can you please share the URL that you have passed ? Are you using correct app id, app code ? Also are you using the correct credentials ? Is it resulting the response with the other APIs ?

Comment: I opened a support ticket and apparently, the large matrix routing API is not available for Freemium credentials.
They said that the Here Credentials team should be contacted to get my customer AppId for Large Matrix Routing API.
And so, now it's done, and I can use the service perfectly.

Comment: According to the FAQs https://developer.here.com/faqs :

8. What other HERE Location Services limits apply to my Freemium or Pro plan?

The following features are excluded. Please contact us if you are interested in one or more of these:

    Electronic Horizon in the HERE SDK (Premium Edition)
    Geovisualization REST API (Geovisualization via JavaScript is included)
    Tracking REST API. For a free trial, go to https://tracking.here.com and select "Try our app".
    Advertising Data Services
    Large-Scale Matrix Routing
    Live Sense SDK Beta

Answer (score 0):

Please use the Production environment, where the credentials are valid and would be working. Production environment will not contain the "cit" in the url. Also please respond to the comment questions.